# Where is debug mapping file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-proguard

In my android studio project, I enable proguard for debug build type:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-debug.txt'
    }
}
```

The problem is after building the project I cannot find the mapping file! So where is the mapping file for debug build type? Or there is no mapping file for debug build type at all?

Comment: I don't think that there will be one unless you obfuscate your code.

Comment: @ThomasR. Won't set `minifyEnabled` to `true` obfuscate code?

Comment: It depends on your proguard config. Could you please post your config, too?

Comment: @ThomasR. I get it. The code is not obfuscated. It just removes unused methods and variables.